# Errors in SQL syntax affecting single portion of admin WP site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Problem: certain forms within a Wordpress theme do not show in the admin side. Also, it’s not possible to add new forms (when attempted it flashes back to the original page and the database gets “damaged”). There is no error message. The site works fine, because although the needed forms are not visible, they are in the database and can be seen in phpmyadmin. When debugging is enabled in WP, I get this message on the admin forms page:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]
SELECT * FROM"

I’m assuming this is the reason why I’m unable to see/add forms.
Below are the problematic sections from the PHP forms code. Thanks!

-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.4
-- PHP Version: 7.3.6

1

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM ", array() . $wpdb->prefix . "cp_ad_forms ORDER BY id desc" ) );
```

2

```
// gat all the admin fields
    $results = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM ". $wpdb->prefix . $cp_table . " WHERE ". $cp_id ." = %d", $_GET['id'] ) );
```

3

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM ", array(). $wpdb->prefix . "cp_ad_packs ORDER BY pack_id desc" ) );
```

Potential “undefined function _e” problems:

1

```
case 'formbuilder':
    ?>

        <div class="wrap">
        <div class="icon32" id="icon-themes"><br/></div>
        <h2><?php _e('Edit Form Layout','theme') ?></h2>

        <?php cp_admin_info_box(); ?>

        <?php
```

2

```
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="icon32" id="icon-themes"><br/></div>
        <h2><?php _e('Form Layouts','theme') ?>&nbsp;<a class="button add-new-h2" href="?page=layouts&amp;action=addform"><?php _e('Add New','theme') ?></a></h2>
```

3

```
<div class="wrap">
            <div class="icon32" id="icon-themes"><br/></div>
            <h2><?php _e('New Form Layout','theme') ?></h2>
```

Comment: The error message says you have a syntax error near a `SELECT` query (presumably, including a filename and line number). Can you show us the lines of code around that query? The four sections from your SQL dump seem to be unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Sure. Please see the added complete code. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any SELECT queries in the database dump you provided. Are you sure the problem is there and not in the PHP code of your admin forms page?

Comment: As I stated, "I'm assuming" that's where the problem is, based on the error message I'm getting. So,no, I'm not sure and you may be perfectly right indeed. I'll look into the forms code and post it. Thank you again for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Rick, once again, I believe you are correct. However, I’m unable to pinpoint the problematic code within the forms file and the whole file is quite large. So, I posted a few sections (in place of the sql code to avoid confusion) – maybe you can help me to narrow down what’s needed? The posted sections relate to the SELECT queries and the first one in particular triggers an “Array to string conversion” notice. However, I begin to suspect that the problem is related to an “undefined function _e”, so I posted those portions too. Once again, your help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: `_e()` is a native Wordpress function, That shouldn't be an issue. Queries 1 and 3 look wrong, the `, array()` portion should be at the end. I.e. `$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "cp_ad_forms ORDER BY id desc", array() )` instead of `$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM ", array() . $wpdb->prefix . "cp_ad_forms ORDER BY id desc" )`. If this is not your own code but a third-party plugin, maybe there's an update available that fixes this?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do it. Nope, not my code and not a plugin. It's a WP theme that is no longer developed. The problem showed up (along with others) when upgraded to PHP 7x. Everything else has been fixed, only this issue remains (and again the front end works fine) . So, because the problem developed after the upgrade to 7.x, I'd say is definitely a php code issue within that file. As mentioned before, I just can't pinpoint it. If you have any other suggestion, please let me know. Thanks again.